# Creating a variable conditional on multiple cells of a DF using vectorized operations

Tags: r

I want to set myDF$cut to true for rows 2 after where A is true, unless the value of the b cells within those 2 rows adds up to more than 2. I have done it with a for loop but I'm finding it runs quite slowly, so I'm hoping there's a way to avoid the looping.

```
set.seed(55)

myDF <- data.frame( a=as.logical (rbinom(136063,1,0.1)), 
                    b=rbinom(136063,2,0.2))

myDF$cut <- F
for (i in 3:length (myDF$a)) {
if (myDF$a[i-1] & myDF$b[i] <2) myDF$cut[i]<- T
if (myDF$a[i-2]& (myDF$b[i]+myDF$b[i-1]) < 2) myDF$cut[i] <- T 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for example, it is at least 1000 times faster:

```
transform(myDF,
          cut = ifelse( c(FALSE,head(a,-1)) & b<2 |
                          c(FALSE,FALSE,head(a,-2)) & (b+c(0,head(b,-1)) < 2),
                        TRUE,
                        FALSE
          )
)
```